# Calculating the tangent line from a point to the surface of a sphere

Tags: geometry, 3d, tangent-line

I need to calculate the beginning and end points of a line that originates at a point in 3D space and then skims the surface of a sphere at a distance location -- the tangent line, of course. I know [how to do this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleTangentLine.html) in two-dimensions, but am stumped when it comes to three:

[image]

Of course, I realize there are an infinite number of such lines, since the point of contact with the sphere could be anywhere in the circular cross-section. So I suppose I need a solution that allows includes a theta value representing the place on the sphere that I want the line to be tangent to.

(The purpose of this exercise is to calculate occultation in space between the sun and the moon, treating the sun as a point instead of a sphere.)

Comment: Take any plane that passes through the given point and the center of the sphere, and solve it in that plane.

Comment: Makes sense. But I don't know how to calculate that plane

Comment: All those lines form a right circular cone, with its apex at your point. The base is a circle, with a radius smaller than the sphere radius, and center on the line between the point and the center of the sphere. You can solve the base circle radius and position the same way you solve the 2D situation, using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Comment: What's the Pythagorean Theorem? Just kidding! Makes total sense. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably ok here, but you might have more luck in the Mathematic**a** stackexchange since you're using Mathematica. This is the Mathematic**s** stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent lines to the sphere form a cone with apex at the given point $\mathbf p$ and axis the line through $\mathbf p$ and the center $\mathbf c$ of the sphere. (To keep things clearer, I’ll mark *inhomogeneous* Cartesian coordinate vectors with a tilde; if there’s no tilde, this indicates a homogeneous coordinate vector.) The points of tangency lie on the intersection of the sphere with the polar plane of $\mathbf p$. This will be a circle in this polar plane, which is perpendicular to the cone’s axis, with center $\mathbf c'$ at the intersection of the plane and axis. To parameterize this circle, find the radius $r'$ via the Pythagorean theorem, and find a pair of unit vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ that are orthogonal to the axis and each other. The circle is then $$\mathbf q = \mathbf c'+r'\mathbf u\cos\theta+r'\mathbf v\sin\theta.$$ The line through this point be found in any of the usual ways, such as the parametrization $(1-\lambda)\mathbf p+\lambda\mathbf q$.

To keep things clearer in the following, I’ll mark variables that represent *inhomogeneous* Cartesian coordinate vectors with a tilde; no tilde indicates a homogeneous coordinate vector. Representing the sphere by the matrix $$S = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}  I_3 & -\tilde{\mathbf c} \\ \hline -\tilde{\mathbf c}^T & \|\tilde{\mathbf c}\|^2-r^2\end{array}\right],$$ the polar plane to $\mathbf p$ is $\mathbf\pi=S\mathbf p$. (The components of this vectors correspond to the coefficients of the implicit Cartesian equation of the plane.) Use your favorite method to find its intersection with the line through $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf c$. Here, I’ll use the Plücker matrix of the line: $$\mathbf c' = (\mathbf p\mathbf c^T-\mathbf c\mathbf p^T)\mathbf\pi = (\mathbf c^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf p - (\mathbf p^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf c.$$ (The parenthesized quantities on the r.h.s. are just the dot products of $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf c$ with $\mathbf\pi$.) The radius of the circle is found from $$r'^2 = r^2-\|\tilde{\mathbf c}-\tilde{\mathbf c}'\|^2.$$ For the unit vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ of the parametrization, choose one of the cross products of $\tilde{\mathbf c}-\tilde{\mathbf p}$ with the unit basis vectors (at least two of them are guaranteed to be nonzero) and normalize it for $\mathbf u$, and then take $\mathbf u\times(\tilde{\mathbf c}-\tilde{\mathbf p})$, normalized, for $\mathbf v$. You can instead use $\tilde{\mathbf c}-\tilde{\mathbf c}'$ or $\tilde{\mathbf c}'-\tilde{\mathbf p}$ for this calculation; I’m not sure which will provide the best numerical stability.

For your example, I get $$S = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&-100\\0&1&0&50\\0&0&1&-75\\-100&50&-75&17500\end{bmatrix}$$ from which $\mathbf\pi=[400:150:-75:-27500]$. Using the above formula for the axis-plane intersection gives $$\mathbf c' = [400:150:-75:-27500],$$ which corresponds to the inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates $$\tilde{\mathbf c}' = \left({30500\over301},{14900\over301},{22500\over301}\right)$$ and the circle’s radius works out to be $r'=250\sqrt{\frac3{301}}$.

For the unit vector $\tilde{\mathbf u}$, I'll take the cross product that has the greatest norm, $(-150,400,0)^T$, so $\tilde{\mathbf u} = \frac1{\sqrt{73}}(-3,8,0)$ and (according to Mathematica; the radicals are starting to get a bit ugly) $\tilde{\mathbf v}=\left({24\over\sqrt{21973}},{9\over\sqrt{21973}},2\sqrt{{73\over301}}\right)^T$. The parametrization of the circle finally comes out to be approximately $$x = 101.329 - 8.76349 \cos\theta + 4.04095 \sin\theta \\ y= -49.5017 + 
 23.3693 \cos\theta + 1.51536 \sin\theta \\ z = 74.7508 + 
 24.5825 \sin\theta.$$

Depending on what it is you want to do with this, it might be more convenient to work with the tangent cone as a whole. It turns out that its matrix is easily computed from $\mathbf p$ and $C$: $$C_{cone} = (\mathbf p^TC\mathbf p)C - (C\mathbf p)(C\mathbf p)^T.$$ Note that the second term isn’t a dot product; it’s the tensor product of $C\mathbf p$ with itself.